# Show one div and hide another div in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, button

I want show one element on button click and hide another element on same button click. Here is my code

[My Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evbpuy)

I am able to show sub div but I want to hide that element which contain "show sub content" button on same button click. Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do like below with single function, working example is here on the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n8saq1)

In the component file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  showMainContent: Boolean = true;

  constructor() {}

   ShowHideButton() {
      this.showMainContent = this.showMainContent ? false : true;
   }
}
```

And in the template file

```
<div *ngIf="!showMainContent">
  <button (click)="ShowHideButton()">Show Sub content</button>
  My Main content
</div>
<div *ngIf="showMainContent">
  Sub Content
  <button (click)="ShowHideButton()">Show Main Content</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank u so much.. :)

Comment: @Javascript, even you needn't make a function just: < button (click)="showMainContent=!showMainContent">click< /button>

Comment: @Eliseo yeah that's also correct, but if we want to execute some lines of code, we should write a function. And your suggestion is super fine and simple

Comment: Instead of using ternary you can simply write
ShowHideButton() {
      this.showMainContent = !this.showMainContent;
   }

Comment: @VijayBarot yeah as **Eliseo** said in the comments of this answer

Comment: Hi @JavascriptLover-SKT can you please help me in this. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9cuejm I have added more sub divs which will be hidden first then click on eash button for that sub section related section will open and main section will hide and vise versa. can you please help.

Comment: @vedankitakumbhar Yeah, I already started look into your problem :-), 5 mins back forked your code from Stackblitz posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51947534/multiple-conditions-in-ngif-in-angular-6

Answer (score 3):

Determine whether to show or hide based on the current state. If it's currently `true`, then make it `false`. If it's currently `false`, then make it `true`.

```
ToggleButton() {
  this.showSelected = !this.showSelected;
}
```

Here's the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3dezzk?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it like this way. No need to initialize **showMainContent** variable.

```
<div *ngIf="!showMainContent">
   <button (click)="showMainContent=!showMainContent">Show Sub content</button>
   My Main content
</div>
<div *ngIf="showMainContent">
   Sub Content
   <button (click)="showMainContent=!showMainContent">Show Main Content</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Sanjog_V can you please help me in this. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9cuejm I have added more sub divs which will be hidden first then click on eash button for that sub section related section will open and main section will hide and vise versa. can you please help.

Answer (score 1):

Just reasign the variable with the opposite value of it

```
ShowButton() {
  this.showSelected = !this.showSelected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions,

Initalize while you declare the variable instead of assigning in constructor,

```
 showSelected: boolean = false;
```

Inside the function toggle the value using **`!`**

```
 ToggleButton() {
      this.showSelected = !this.showSelected;
 }
```

[`DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wptd5t?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing ngIf for n time, you could also write ngIf else:

```
<div *ngIf="isLoggedIn; else loggedOut">
  Welcome back, friend.
</div>

<ng-template #loggedOut>
  Please friend, login.
</ng-template>
```

or ngIf else then syntax:

```
<ng-container
  *ngIf="isLoggedIn; then loggedIn; else loggedOut">
</ng-container>

<ng-template #loggedIn>
  <div>
   Welcome back, friend.
  </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #loggedOut>
  <div>
    Please friend, login.
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

The choice depends in how many check you need to do.